# Why "The user will always be prompted to authorize access to your application, even if access was previously granted."

Tags: oauth, twitter-oauth

I am wondering what is the reason behind having "The user will always be prompted to authorize access to your application, even if access was previously granted." mentioned in Twitter 3-legged authorization (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization)?

I am very confused, what does that mean? Does it mean if a user authorize my app and I capture the tokens in my database, my app users will have to go through the whole authorization process next visit?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not what it means -- once you're signed in, you're signed in.

If, however, they wipe the app from their device, thus deleting the access token, they'll still need to reauthorize -- authorizations are tied to installations, not specific apps.

For example, I've had to reauthorize Tweetbot for Android each time I wipe my Android device -- it needs to get a new access token each time. Access tokens aren't automatically provisioned just because you've installed the app once.

[Here's a great O'Reilly article on three-legged OAuth.](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1381-how-to-use-three-legged-oauth/).

Comment: "Twitter doesn't "remember" I've authorized it." How come my app is showing in https://twitter.com/settings/applications then for every account who is using it?

Comment: Hmm, that's probably a bad phrasing. Certainly Twitter has server-side records, and you can revoke the app's authorization server-side. I've clarified the wording.